# How to space edges evenly using LoopTools addon

Tags: modeling, add-on

I have added the subdivision modifier to my mesh, and the loop cuts are uneven. Im trying to use the LoopTools addon but the result is messed up. Is there a method to get the edges evenly spaced using an addon or some other method?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can fix your problem with your current shape, but you can easily simplify your mesh with some edge dissolutions, unless you need all these edges for some reasons?

You can try with the *Edge Flow* addon though, activate and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (or *Edge* panel) > *Set Linear* (and activate *Space Evenly* in the *Operator* box).

For a flat surface, *Edge Flow* would work fine, here is what the *Edge > Set Flow* tool gives (and again, play with the *Operator* box parameters):

[image]

Comment: Although not the best result if the mesh has been extruded, its still helpful for the flat mesh, so it did what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: why do you need so many edge loops? If you have no reason you should dissolve most of them

Comment: practicing modelling a radio and has lots of controls and sliders and screens. So I make lots of  Edge loops, so I can make circles, so 4 faces make up a circle and have quads. https://ibb.co/TcyftM7

Comment: why not but as your surface is flat you could create ngons without any artefact

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I can get away with Ngons since it's a flat surface. But I'm trying to do the right thing with topology so learning the correct way becomes a regulation for me and not to become a bad 3D designer. Everyday I learn and try to adapt the correct methods of topology theory :)

Comment: I think the right thing is to have the good result, ngons or tris are not bad as long as they don't create artefacts